# Can you still set a background color style in Textedit in Mavericks?

Tags: textedit, formatting

I had some background text color styles on my old mac and now have Mavericks - but I don't see any way to create a style for a highlighter-type background (for a sentence, paragraph etc.) - The Fonts panel doesn't have background color anymore, just an entire document background color.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality again?

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on whether your document is formatted as rich text (`.rtf`, `.docx`, etc.) or plain text (`.txt`).

If your document is plain text, I'm not sure why you would want to do this anyway, since your color changes won't be saved when you save the document.

When the document is formatted as rich text, you should see the rich text editor toolbar at the top of your window. The highlighting button is in the center, and looks like an "a" with a red slash through it (if you have no highlight color selected). [image: img of highlight button] When there is a highlight color selected, it looks like an "a" with the highlight color as the background.[image: Highlight button Red]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh for the love of Mary, Michael and Joseph, thank you so much CzarLogic...  I thought I clicked that before and didn't get anything -- OR I saw the "a" and assumed it was some font thing. Must be because its Friday. lol    You are wonderful, thank you.  :D

Comment: Not a problem - you're very welcome!